# How to render output panel active when sObject has no value

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to build code that hides a block (outputPanel) when it has no value or the value is false. Home_Schooled__c is defined as a checkbox.  The code provided actually works if I check, then uncheck the Home_Schooled__c block.  I would like it to work on initial entry onto the page.  The snipit of code is:

```
    <apex:panelGroup >
    <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Home Schooled"/>
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:inputField value="{!interest.Home_Schooled__c}" >
         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="highSchoolPanel"/>
    </apex:inputField>

    </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel id="highSchoolPanel">
    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="Column" rendered="{!studentType=='Freshman' && !interest.Home_Schooled__c==True}">

    <apex:panelGroup >
        <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School Country"/>
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_Country__c}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="highSchoolNamePanel"/>
    </apex:inputField>

    <apex:panelGroup >
        <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School State/Province"/>
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_State__c}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="highSchoolNamePanel"/>
    </apex:inputField>

    <apex:panelGroup >
        <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School Name"/><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:outputPanel id="highSchoolNamePanel">
        <apex:selectList value="{!con.High_School__c}" multiselect="false" size="1" styleClass="inputRequired">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!HighSchoolOptions}"/>
            <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" rerender="highSchoolOtherLabel, highSchoolOtherField" />
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel id="highSchoolOtherLabel"><apex:panelGroup rendered="{!con.High_School__c==otherHighschoolId}">
        <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School Other"/>
    </apex:panelGroup></apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="highSchoolOtherField"><apex:inputField value="{!con.High_School_Other__c}" rendered="{!con.High_School__c==otherHighschoolId}" /></apex:outputPanel>


     <apex:panelGroup >
        <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School Address"/>
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_Address__c}" />

    <apex:panelGroup >
        <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School City"/>
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_City__c}" />

    <apex:panelGroup >
        <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School Zip Code"/>
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_Zip_Code__c}" />

    <apex:panelGroup >
        <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="High School GPA"/>
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_GPA__c}" />

    <apex:panelGroup >
        <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="ACT score"/>
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:inputField value="{!interest.ACT_Score__c}" />

    <apex:panelGroup >
        <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="HS Graduation Date" /><apex:outputText styleclass="req" value=""/>
        <br/>
        <div class="small">Approximate date graduating from High School</div>
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:inputField value="{!interest.High_School_Grad_Date__c}" styleClass="inputRequired" />

    </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

If you need to see more code, please let me know.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has the following check:

```
rendered="{!studentType=='Freshman' && !interest.Home_Schooled__c==True}
```

This reads: If ((studentType == 'Freshman')  AND (NOT Home_Schooled__c == true))

Did you mean to negate the check on Home_Schooled__c? You only need one exclamation mark when dealing with merge fields or controller/object properties. I suspect what you want is:

```
rendered="{!studentType=='Freshman' && interest.Home_Schooled__c==True}
```

**Update:**

Based on the response in the comments, I would try (formatted for easier reading):

```
rendered="{!studentType == 'Freshman' && 
     (interest.Home_Schooled__c == null ||  
     interest.Home_Schooled__c == False)}
```

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what I want.  My problem is that Home_Schooled__c has no value when the page is initially rendered, so it is neither true or false.

Comment: Are you initializing the Interest__c object in the controller to have an initial value?

Comment: You should be able to check for null. Otherwise setting up a custom property in an extension controller might be an option.

Comment: I tried using ISNULL and ISEMPTY, but the compiler said that Home_Schooled__c is 'incorrect argument type'

Comment: Did you try `Home_Schooled__c == null`?

Comment: It still does not act properly.  I have to check and uncheck the Home_Schooled__c field to get it to work.  It's like it is not recognizing the value null.

Comment: I figured it out.  I had to add the rerender of the outputpanel to a higher block of code.  It works great now.  Thank you.